# Install Windows or Ubuntu first after clean wipe?

Tags: dual-boot

So some stuff happened and my hard drive was completely wiped out, I previously had a dual boot system between windows 10 and Ubuntu, I would like to do the same now. What I would like to know is which would be easier? Installing Ubuntu first and then Windows or vice versa? Also is it better to make partitions and install or install both of them together?

Answer (score 3):

You should install Windows first, because Windows wipes out GRUB if Ubuntu is installed first, so in short you won't be able to boot your machine into Ubuntu, unless you re-install GRUB from a Ubuntu live USB stick.

As for partitioning, you need two separate partitions; because every OS uses a different file system, namely ext4 for Ubuntu and NTFS for Windows, I suggest partitioning using gparted from a Ubuntu live USB stick, install Windows then install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am kinda new to this so can you please tell me to what format they should be partitioned to?

Comment: Aa i said in my answer the windows partition needs to be formatted as ntfs, while ubuntu partition needs to be formatted as ext4. Just split your HDD to 2 drives the first is a ntfs partition for windows, and the second is a ext4 partition for ubuntu.