# To create a dual-boot system: which OS should I install first?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-10, mbr

I want to reset my laptop's hard-drive and create a dual-boot system, using both Windows 10 (for gaming) and Ubuntu 18.04 (for everything else). Currently my PC uses Ubuntu 18.04 as sole operating system.

After formatting the hard-disk, what should I install first? Ubuntu or Windows?

I know that in the second case I need to restore the Ubuntu's GRUB because Windows has this tendency of overwrite the master boot record, but that a minor issue for me.

Thanks!

Comment: windows first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826322/install-windows-or-ubuntu-first-after-clean-wipe/826329):

"You should install Windows first, because Windows wipes out GRUB if Ubuntu is installed first, so in short you won't be able to boot your machine into Ubuntu, unless you re-install GRUB from a Ubuntu live USB stick.

As for partitioning, you need two separate partitions; because every OS uses a different file system, namely ext4 for Ubuntu and NTFS for Windows, I suggest partitioning using gparted from a Ubuntu live USB stick, install Windows then install Ubuntu."

Comment: Just to be sure: while formatting the hard-drive would I also delete all of the partitions? Or do I need to do by myself with gparted?

Comment: when you format the hard-drive, it delete all of the partitions automatically, so you don't need to delete partitions manually by yourself.