# im using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and want to install win 10 along side. how plz?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

im using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS want to install Win 10 along side
im using a 500 GB hard disk with:
4 GB swap . primary------------
150 MB /root .primary---------------
345 MB /home . primary-----------

plz ive searched internet and found answers but im confused on how to use ***Disk Utility*** to create a C-partion for win, also should i creat another partion for my files or my /home partion is enough ?
also what is ***Grub*** ?

Comment: If you could, it is much easier to install windows 10 first then add Ubuntu to it as the Ubuntu installation is much more transparent and allow you to specifically install it into a partition. UEFI installation works best as Ubuntu simply add an entry to your efi partion alongside windows. Windows should show up in Ubuntu and you can switch between grub and windows boot manager using efibootmgr in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Grub is less scary then it sounds, in fact it is incredibly friendly.

Ubuntu having been in this dynamic of dual-booting with windows from the start, has become very experienced with dual booting problematics.

Grub is the bootloader for most linux distributions.

it is faster, more configurable, ect ect ect...

trust it.

as per : [Install Windows or Ubuntu first after clean wipe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826322/install-windows-or-ubuntu-first-after-clean-wipe/826329)

you should install windows first (as a complete format of the disk) and then install ubuntu. the other order is too hard for you to do.

Comment: yes but this is during installation of ubuntu but ive already installed it im running on it right now. is there something im missunderstanding ?

Comment: so what is wrong?

Comment: isn't this pic up there is during install ? i dont want to install ubuntu, i want to install win 10 :(

Comment: oh you changed your post. I was also misslead because you listed out you /root and /home sizes... Honestly I don't recommend doing it that way around. if you can back up your files first. The best approach to dual booting is wiping the drive durring the win10 install and then installing ubuntu afterwards. https://www.google.com/search?q=should+I+install+windows+or+ubuntu+first%3F&oq=should+I+install+windows+or+ubuntu+first%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.14191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: well thats a way i dont wanna dig in for a really big reason- but i've found this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

i will try to follow that :(

Comment: it's really really so much easier to do the opposite, but if you really really feel up to it..

Comment: hey one last question, can i just plug in my usb drive and start Win 10 installation and edit my 350 GB partition to allocate a 40 GB for Win 10 C Drive and call it a day ? yes or no :D

Comment: no. obbviously no. or we'd tell you that that's the easier way.

Comment: thats right im sorry lol